# Postgres trigger DateUpdated failed

Tags: postgresql

I have a column named DTUpdated of type timestamp with time zone.

I created a function to automatically update that column with every modification:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."RowModifiedFunction"()
    RETURNS trigger AS $$

BEGIN
    NEW.DTUpdated = clock_timestamp();  
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

and apply it with a trigger in that table

```
CREATE TRIGGER "RowModifiedTrigger"
    BEFORE UPDATE 
    ON public."Departments"
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE public."RowModifiedFunction"();
```

But when I modify a column I get the error:

> "Record new has no field dtupdated" (in lowercase).

Answer (score 2):

Postgresql requires "these quotes" on any name that contains uppercase.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."RowModifiedFunction"()
    RETURNS trigger AS $$

BEGIN
    NEW."DTUpdated" = clock_timestamp();  
    RETURN NEW;
END;
```

Comment: it's best to just use lowercase for everything, then you don't need quotes :)

Answer (score 0):

if you column is case sensitive, use double quotes:

```
NEW."DTUpdated" = clock_timestamp();
```

NB: usually setting default value to `now()` instead of such trigger. The only case you need trigger if you want it to fire on specific modifications only